# Serial upvoting

Tags: discussion

This is not a question, it's a request to the user who serial upvoted my posts on April 24th 2019 and to other people who might do serial upvote/downvote on anyone else posts.

Please stop this.
This does not do anything good to you, the user you are targeting or the website.

[image]

Edit:
In case someone wants to know what happens the next day

[image]

[It gets reverted](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: Very worried Behaviour for the community . This year  seems people are doing much serial voting (:

Comment: I didnt get it. What is the reason for serial upvoting?

Comment: me neither.....

Comment: @Marius may be they are your fans ;)

Comment: I had the same problem few months back with +190 and its reversal in next day when informed to Moderator(Amit Bera or Marius).

Comment: Could be they are looking to get a badge based on number of upvotes.  Silly, but the best reason I can think of.

Comment: Related, serial voting FAQ on meta.stackexchange: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/271271)