# Serial Downvoting

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Just like the Serial Upvoting mentioned [here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/serial-upvoting), I am facing serial downvoting on my questions and answers these days.

I don't know who is doing this but I have noticed some suspicious activity.

For example:

- [Magento 2: Override ACL using custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270596/magento-2-override-acl-using-custom-module) (Question)
- [Why admin added to the site?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273023/why-admin-added-to-the-site/273024#273024) (Answer)
- [Suddenly customer_grid_flat table delete in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268774/suddenly-customer-grid-flat-table-delete-in-magento-2/268778#268778) (Answer)

I can assume that a person can cast downvote if my answer does not work for him/her, but what is wrong with my [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270596/magento-2-override-acl-using-custom-module).

I request the respected moderators to please look into this matter.

Comment: ... happens on meta too ... ;)

Comment: 3v9 ... and counting :P

Comment: 5-10 for the record :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Getting a few downvotes does not mean serial downvoting.
Your question has 7 downvotes and 3 upvotes (at the time I'm writing this).
One person cannot downvote more than once on a question. So it is not serial downvoting. The downvotes came from different people.
As for your answers, they have 1 downvote each. Again not serial.
Anyway, I've looked into this and there is nothing "illegal" showing up on the radar.

Answer (score 2):

Don want to post as comment ....

Marius is right in general, but it looks definitly wrong to me - *unnormal voting*.

Every day day there are poor, but upvoted questions. Same for not downvoted oneliners. This is a really well explained question, that got -10 so far.

Seems not correct to me, since it doesn't fit to other voting behavoir.

Maybe just "groug pressor" ... if it already has negative score, donwvote - it has to be wrong ... ;)

Comment: Thanks for understanding my concern @sv3n.