# Someone Downvoting my answer Without any reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes

i just saw in my reputations that someone has down voted  my answers simultaneously with any reason
I there any way that we can restrict that user have to write a proper reason before downvote

[image]

Comment: I have also come across this behavior. without any reason, a person downvoted my answer and then gives some what similar answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no sign of serial downvoting reported by the admin tools.
I guess someone just didn't like your answers.
For more details you can look on this similar question: [Serial Downvoting](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2539/146)